# Conditional field validation that depends on another field

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I need to change the validation of some field in a form. The validator is configured via a quite large yml file. I wonder if there is any way to do validation on two fields at once.
In my case I have two fields that cannot be both empty. At least one has to be filled.

Unfortunately till now I just could see that the validation are defined on a per-field basis, not on multiple fields together.

The question is: is it possible in the standard yml configurations to perform the aforementioned validation?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to look at [Custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html), especially [Class Constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator).

I won't copy paste the whole code, just the parts which you will have to change.

---

Extends the `Constraint` class.

<kbd>src/Acme/DemoBundle/Validator/Constraints/CheckTwoFields.php</kbd>

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CheckTwoFields extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'You must fill the foo or bar field.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
            return 'CheckTwoFieldsValidator';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
            return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

Define the validator by extending the `ConstraintValidator` class, `foo` and `bar` are the 2 fields you want to check:

<kbd>src/Acme/DemoBundle/Validator/Constraints/CheckTwoFieldsValidator.php</kbd>

```php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CheckTwoFieldsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($protocol, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ((empty($protocol->getFoo())) && (empty($protocol->getBar()))) {
            $this->context->addViolationAt('foo', $constraint->message, array(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the validator:

<kbd>src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml</kbd>

```yml
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AcmeEntity:
    constraints:
        - Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints\CheckTwoFields: ~
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I didn't tested my code, I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: is a solution similar to this possible using sfValidator classes?

Comment: I only know Symfony2, not Symfony1, sorry.

Comment: @A.L on public function **validatedBy()  remeber to specific all class path** like **Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints\CheckTwoFieldsValidator**

Comment: @Massimo212121 I followed the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#creating-the-validator-itself), only the name of the class is returned.

Comment: @A.L i followed to but with WebTestCase have problem to find the class, for this my advise is specify the class name in all case :)