# Symfony2 - validate a group of fields (and change values) only if one of them is filled

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I'm working on profile edit form type. I have problem with how to validate fields `oldPassword` and `password` only if one of them are filled. Firstly I set `required => false`, but I cannot find how turn off validation and turn on only if field `oldPassword` is filled, or repeated field `password`. Also, if validation wasn't done, values of these fields will not be processed into DB.

In form type class I have this:

```
        ->add('oldPassword', 'password', array('label' => 'Old password', 'required' => false, 'mapped' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true))
        ->add('password', 'repeated', array('type' => 'password', 'required' => false, 'invalid_message' => 'New passwords must equal', 'first_options'  => array('label' => 'New password'), 'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat new password'), 'error_bubbling' => true,))
```

In my entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)    
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = "4",
 *      minMessage = "Password must have at least 4 characters"         
 * )       
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
 *     message = "Old password must equal with current"
 * )
 */
protected $oldPassword;
```

And in controller nothing special:

```
public function profileAction(Request $request)
{
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();

    if(!$user)
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'error',
            'User with ID ' . $user->getId() . ' does not exist'
        );
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_dashboard'));
    }

    $form = $this->createForm('user', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request); 

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $em->persist($user);

        try {
            $em->flush();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            // sth
        }
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'success',
            'Profile was successfuly edited'
        );

        $em->refresh($user);
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeUserBundle:Admin:profile.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

And now I need that these fields (`oldPassword`, `password`) will not be validated if there are not filled and also will not change current values, because there are more fields such as `username`, `email`, `name`, etc.

Is this work for FormType or Controller or both?

Comment: Have you tried using form events? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: @Alberto thank you for your response. This will me help me in the future but for this problem I found something similiar to my problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786365/symfony2-how-to-validate-an-input-field-is-not-blank-only-when-checkbox-is-tru. Using validation_groups is not a bad choice I think.