# Required field in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a FormType class

```
<?php
class FormType extends AbstractType
{        
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('price', 'integer', [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Tranche/QF minimal(e)',
            ])
            ->add('reductionPourcentage', 'integer', [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Reduction in Pourcentage'
            ])
            ->add('reductionEuros', 'money', [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Reduction in Euro'
            ])
        ;
    }
```

I want to required the fields **reductionPourcentage** and **reductionEuros**. 
But the user just has to fill one of them. Not both of them.

How can I do that in a simple way with the FormBuilderInterface?

Do I have to use a Constraint : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your wish... Maybe a choice field...

Comment: Someone find an answer about realtive fields. [here is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786365/symfony2-how-to-validate-an-input-field-is-not-blank-only-when-checkbox-is-tru/20802838#20802838)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constraint or an [expression](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) constraint (do not set any of this fields as `required` and use one of these constraints to test that one of them and not both is set)