# Symfony2 Validator Constraint GreaterThan on other property

Tags: php, validation, symfony

My validations are defined in a yaml file like so;

```
# src/My/Bundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
My\Bundle\Model\Foo:
    properties:
        id:
            - NotBlank: 
                groups: [add]
        min_time:
            - Range:
                min: 0
                max: 99
                minMessage: "Min time must be greater than {{ limit }}"
                maxMessage: "Min time must be less than {{ limit }}"
                groups: [add]
        max_time:
            - GreaterThan:
                value: min_time
                groups: [add]
```

How do I use the validator constraint `GreaterThan` to check against another property?
E.g make sure max_time is greater than min_time?

I know I can create a custom constraint validator, but surely you can do it using the `GreaterThan` constraint.
Hopefully I am missing something really simple here

Comment: I don't think that these annotations can use another field. See [one of my answer about validating a field depending on another field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471812/conditional-field-validation-that-depends-on-another-field/20472214#20472214), it's not complicated to implement.

Comment: @n.1 I thought that was what I would have to do.  If you write this as answer I will accept it (so others can easily see the solution)

Comment: In fact I'm note sure it is impossible with *simple* annotations, so this is not a good answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to look at [Custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html), especially [Class Constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator).

I won't copy paste the whole code, just the parts which you will have to change.

#### src/My/Bundle\Model\Foo/Validator/Constraints/CheckTime.php

Define the validator, `min_time` and `max_time` are the 2 fields you want to check.

```php
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CheckTime extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Max time must be greater than min time';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
            return 'CheckTimeValidator';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
            return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

#### src/My/Bundle/Validator/Constraints/CheckTimeValidator.php

Define the validator:

```php
<?php

namespace My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CheckTimeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($foo, Constraint $constraint)
    {
            if ($foo->getMinTime() > $foo->getMaxTime()) {
                $this->context->addViolationAt('max_time', $constraint->message, array(), null);
            }
    }
}
```

#### src/My/Bundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

Use the validator:

```yml
My\Bundle\Entity\Foo:
    constraints:
        - My\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\CheckTime: ~
```

Answer (score 23):

Try [GreaterThan](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/GreaterThan.html) constraint with option [propertyPath](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/GreaterThan.html#propertypath):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 * @Assert\GreaterThan(propertyPath="minTime")
 */
 protected $maxTime;
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Symfony 2 ... OP was asking about Symfony 2.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a [Callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) validator.  Custom validators work too, but probably an overkill if this is a one off validation and won't be re-used in other parts of the application.

With Callback validators you can define them on the same Entity/Model and are called at Class level.

In your case

```
// in your My\Bundle\Model\Foo:
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function checkMaxTimeGreaterThanMin($foo, Constraint $constraint)
{
        if ($foo->getMinTime() > $foo->getMaxTime()) {
            $this->context->addViolationAt('max_time', $constraint->message, array(), null);
        }
}
```

or if you're using YAML

```
My\Bundle\Model\Foo:
    constraints:
        - Callback: [checkMaxTimeGreaterThanMin]
```