# Check start date and end date to be a period of two weeks in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Could someone assist me with this. I'm having a trouble with creating a query or how to add changes to createAction to achieve the following. On clicking create it checks if a payroll period is valid, because in the payroll week table it is populated with a one week while the user enters a two week period.

Payroll period: payrollperiodid, start date, enddate and state
Payroll Week: id, startDAte, enddate, numofdays, normal hours.

for eg. user enters startdate: 16-07-2017 enddate: 29-07-2017 in payroll period then in the payroll week table period 1 startdate: 16-07-2017 endDate:22-07-2017 period 2 startdate:23-07-2017 enddate:29-07-2017.

Thus the period would be considered valid else error, and then also on create once the period is valid checks if it exists in the payroll period table else error. But i'm not sure how to add the part that ensures that the user enters a period of 2weeks. >7days <=14days, I wouldn't want to use hard numbers how could i achieve this

```
    public function createAction(Request $request,$startDate, $endDate)
        {
            $entity = new Payrollperiod();
            $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findByPayrollPeriod(array('startDate'=>$startDate,'endDate'=> $endDate));
                    if ($entity){
                    $this->addFlash('error','ERROR!  Payroll Period exist');
                     return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_create'));
                    }
                         $em->persist($entity);
                         $em->flush();
                         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
            }       
                return array(
                    'entity' => $entity,
                    'form'   => $form->createView(), );
        }

       public function findByPayrollPeriod($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:PayrollWeek
                    WHERE startDate = :startDate or endDate = :endDate'
            )
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
            ->getResult();
    }
```

****Updates****

```
<?php

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

/**
 * Payrollperiod
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="PayrollPeriod")
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 */
class Payrollperiod
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="payrollperiodid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $payrollperiodid;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type("DateTime")
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type("DateTime")
     *
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="State", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * 
     */
    private $state;

    public function getPayrollperiodid() {
        return $this->payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function getStartdate() {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    public function getEnddate() {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    public function getState() {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setPayrollperiodid($payrollperiodid) {
        $this->payrollperiodid = $payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function setStartdate(\DateTime $startdate) {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
    }

    public function setEnddate(\DateTime $enddate) {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;
    }

    public function setState($state) {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * Render a payrollPeriodID as a string.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
     public function __toString()
    {
     return (string) $this->getPayrollperiodid();

    }

     /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */

    public function validatePayrollPeriod(Payrollperiod $Payrollperiod,ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    $conflicts = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')
        ->findbyPayrollPeriod($Payrollperiod->getstartDate(), $Payrollperiod->getendDate())
    ;

    if (count($conflicts) > 0) {
        $context->buildViolation('Start date and end date exists')
                ->atPath('startdate')
                ->addViolation();

    }
}


}



    public function findbyPayrollPeriod(\DateTime $startDate, \DateTime $endDate)
        {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

            return $qb->andWhere('e.startDate = :startDate AND e.endDate = :endDate')
                ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
                ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute()
            ;
        }
```

But i'm still not getting the error message, am I missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can solve this in various ways. If this is a common problem (and/ or you prefer a global solution) use the [Class Constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator). If you don't mind a 'local' solution look at [Callback Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

Both are explained in the documentation pages. Another reference is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138699/symfony2-validator-constraint-greaterthan-on-other-property).

All that is left is how to calculate the difference between dates for that I'd suggest using PHP's [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.diff.php) as something like:

```
$days = $startDate->diff($endDate)->days;
if ($days <= 7 && $days > 14) {
    // build my constraint error message because the period is invalid.
}
```

---

## Update #1

*So let me first say after our comment spam, maybe start somewhere a little lighter. It seems your diving in right in the middle without any foundation on Symfony and/ or even PHP. Symfony has excellent tutorials and examples, but if you can't apply those your going to have a hard time.*

> The callback validate is only to check the difference between the two dates. An entity in general should not talk to the database but just itself / related entity classes.

```
class Payrollperiod {
    ...

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validatePayrollPeriod(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
        $days = $this->startdate->diff($this->enddate)->days;
        if ($days <= 7 && $days > 14) {
            $context->buildViolation('There have to be at least 7 and a maximum of 13 days for your payroll period.')
                ->atPath('enddate') // this is where the message is bound to, can be either start or end date depending on where you prefer.
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

> Your `findbyPayrollPeriod` seems valid, as long as it is in your `PayrollperiodRepository` class file. And you do want to have a single equals check and not see if ranges overlap etc.

*This function could also be handled using doctrine's [unique constraints](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-uniqueconstraint) on multiple columns eg (user, startdate) and (user, enddate). This should give you an error when you attempt to add it as it then requires a unique value for the two. Even without the `findbyPayrollPeriod` function.*

> In your controller your repository line has multiple problems.
>
> 1. You are using an array for arguments not two arguments as the function has.
> 2. You are overwriting your form data entity because you are using the same variable name.
> 3. And your `$startdate` and `$enddate` appear like magic. They are from the entity, so use the getters.
>
> And as a side note you might not want to redirect on the flash, but just continue as normal (so you don't loose your form data).
>
> All in all you would get something partially like:

```
...

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityExists = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')
        ->findByPayrollPeriod($entity->getStartdate(), $entity->getEnddate());

    // If the entity does not exist we can add it and redirect to the new page.
    if (!$entityExists) {

        // Add our form entity to the database.
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        
        // redirectToRoute is a controller helper function and is a tiny bit shorter.
        return $this->redirectToRoute('payrollperiod_show', array(
            'payrollperiodid' => $entity->getPayrollperiodid()
        ));
    }

    // Form is valid but we didn't return anything so far.
    // So there is an entity with the same period start or end.
    // Add a flash and show the form again.
    $this->addFlash('error', 'A payroll period is already present
                              with the same start or end date.');
}

return ...
```

Comment: This creates 'custom' form validation. So the form is no longer valid, where depends on what method you pick. Try the 'reading things approach' there are plenty of code samples on the pages provided that actually teach you what it is does and where it goes.. And return when you have an actual problem, show what you have tried, what doesn't work, etc.. (the [SO Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) guidelines..)

Comment: I'm new to using symfony that's why I asked, not sure to do the custom validate. I tried this @Assert\Range
     * ( 
     * min= "today", max="+2weeks"
     * ) but it keep  saying the date isn't valid.

Comment: Well that is explained in the pages I linked. The range validator only applies to a single field (could be used on multiple to test eg within 2 weeks from now or something, but does not compare to another). When you want to compare one field vs another you need something else.

Comment: The documentations doesn't really tell me much in ensuring that the user enters 14 days using call back or class constraint. Or I'm not understanding at the moment. Is the call back or class constraint to check if the period exist?

Comment: No. 'im not sure how to add the part that ensures that the user enters a period of 2weeks. >7days <=14days' this is that. If you want to check if there is an existing record you can just use your custom repository function findByPayrollPeriod. Albeit, it probably needs some query tweaking it just compares start vs start or end vs end. And does not check any value in the range between it, etc.

Comment: I didn't check that because i only want to check if that start date and end date exits if they exist then the user gets an error after which checks against to payroll week to see if it exists also. But the only thing is that in payroll week table its populated with one week while the user should enter only two weeks.

Comment: Well the callback constraint + the code snippet to check the day count between two dates should solve that no? Just add it to the Payrollperiod entity.

Comment: Didn't understand your question

Comment: Well I said the constraint + day check part would solve that problem (range between two date properties). But I assume it doesn't, so whats exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to create the callback constraint.

Comment: Its using annotations in your entity just like any other validation constraint (like your range), the only extra thing is the validate function - again see the [Callback Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#configuration) so instead of Author you have Payrollperiod

Comment: I have edited the question to what I currently have but the error message still not executing. Did leave out something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150071/discussion-between-sue-and-jenne-van-der-meer).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve the issue, the following way

```
//create new trait
<?php

namespace yourBundlePath\Form\Type\Utility;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 *
 * @package Daim\CoreBundle\Form\Type\Utility
 */
trait ContainerTrait
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $containerObject;

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @return ContainerInterface
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        return $this->containerObject = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @return ContainerInterface
     */
    public function getContainer()
    {        
        return $this->containerObject;
    }
}

//form
use yourBundlePath\Form\Type\Utility\ContainerTrait;
class yourFormClass
{
   //call after the class declaration
    use ContainerTrait;

 $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
           $form = $event->getForm();
           $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
           $startDate = $form->get('startDate')->getData();
           $endDate = $form->get('endDate')->getData();
           $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->findByPayrollPeriod(array('startDate'=>$startDate,'endDate'=> $endDate));
           if ($entity){
            $form->get('startDate')->addError(
                    new FormError(
                     'ERROR!  Payroll Period exist'
                    )
                );
           }
         }
    );
```

Also you can refer the url: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Thanks but I seems to get a error at getContainer. Also how can I do a from validation to ensure that user enters a two week period.

Comment: Hey siju, could you tell me what can be done mitigate the getContainer error, first time using add event listener so i'm no too sure about it

Comment: Hi Sue, It is working in my project. I don't know what is the missing in your project. i will check it in my project asap and will inform you. Please check if your two dates have 14 days to ensure that user enters a two weeks period

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm lost at that point because not every period will have 2 full weeks. How would I ensure that where exactly would I check for that

Comment: It just gives me an error at get container not sure if something was missing

Comment: Hey siju did you see what I was missing for mine to work?