# Symfony Forms Assert

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, assert

I have Event class that has a field like this :

```
class Event
{
    ......
    /**
     * @var datetime $date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_debut_inscri", type="datetime")
     * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("today UTC")
     */
     protected $dateDebutInscri;
     ......
}
```

This field is hidden when a checkbox is checked and it's set to null in the controller, the problem is when this field is hidden the Assert error message still appears and that makes me unable to submit my form

I want it to be null by default and if the user chooses to fill this field it must be greater or equal than the current date

I was wondering if i could do soomething like :

```
* @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("today UTC") OR @Assert\IsNull()
```

where it requires only one of the two Assert to be true

PS : "dateDebutInscri" is in french and it means the date when the inscription to the event is open

Comment: Hi. This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32394077/symfony-conditional-form-validation Let me know if you still can't get it to work, and the reason why :) , so I will post an answer with some code.

Comment: that's too much code to add for such a little problem, GroupSequence are a better alternative, thanks anyway

Comment: I was talking about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32603870/4220880 actually, which is definitely not much code and a better solution because it keeps your entity decoupled  from it's validation.

Comment: yeah i saw it later, it seemed very logical but when i tried it it didn't work, don't know why, i appreciate your help, i'm voting you up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to so solve this problem using GroupSequence, it's explained here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/sequence_provider.html

Added some code to my Event class and it's all good

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\GroupSequenceProviderInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\EventRepository")
 * @Assert\GroupSequenceProvider
 */
class Event implements GroupSequenceProviderInterface
{
......
   /**
    * @var datetime $date
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="date_debut_inscri", type="datetime")
    * @Assert\GreaterThanOrEqual("today UTC", groups = {grp1})
    */
    protected $dateDebutInscri;
......

    public function getGroupSequence(){
            $groups = ['Default', 'Event'];

            if(!$this->getMyCheckBox())
            {
                $groups[] = 'grp1';
            }
            return $groups;
    }
}
```