# Assert when a checkbox is checked, Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, assert

I have an entity with some Assert, by default they are all checked, i want to check only some of them based on a checkbox value

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next time try providing more information about your problem

i had a similar problem a few days ago, i think this may help

[Symfony Forms Assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419850/symfony-forms-assert)