# How do I implement dynamic (i.e. not cached) Doctrine Asserts in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine-Entity in my Symfony2-Project, which uses a custom Assert/Constraint to check, if a given date value is before and/or after a given date. This looks like the following simplified code:

In my entity class:

```php
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="entry_entered_at", type="date", nullable=true)
 * @AppBundleAssert\DateRangeConstraint(max = "today")
 */
private $entryEnteredAt;
```

The relevant snippet of the corresponding DateRangeConstraint-class:

```php
new \DateTime($this->max)
```

As you can see, I want to check, if a date is before today. The \DateTime-constructor is able to resolve this to a DateTime-object of today. Nice thing, works fine.

### The problem

But it turns out, that Symfony2 caches all those Doctrine-annotations, so today is always resolved to the day, the cache was lastly cleared and my constraint produces nice form errors.

As a workaround for now, I clear the cache on a daily basis, but I need a better solution.

### The question

So the question is, what would you suggest, how to implement such a dynamic assert/constraint in Symfony2?

I could implement the constraint inside the form, but it should be in the domain of the entity.

## Edit:

I posted as answer and marked it as solution.

Comment: where is your @AppBundleAssert\DateRangeConstraint coming from? isn't that already a custom constraint? and then why not checking the condition within the constraint?

Comment: @LBA yes, this is a custom constraint. My intention was, that this constraint can get a valid DateTime-constructor string as an argument, so it can be reused. In fact, Symfony serializes the DateRangeConstraint object and caches it. So it won't be initialized every time it is called, but is executed with the initialization state, when it was cached.

Comment: I suggest you to post the solution [as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), you'll be able to accept your answer, which will *close* the question.

Comment: @A.L you are right, I extracted my solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution and some answers

It turned out, that the built in *Range* validator is also able to validate a date-range. So I don't need my custom validator at all.

Digging a bit deeper into the built in *Range* constraint and the base *Constraint* class gives the reason, why the built in validators can use dynamic parameters like `today`, but not my incorrect implemented custom validator. The *Constraint* base class has a *__sleep()* method that just stores the object vars and its current values on serialization. Thus, when we don't reinitialize the object with a custom *__wakeup()* method, which would be a false workaround, we only get the cached parameters.

So besides the fact, that the builtin *Range* constraint already solves my problem, I simply should have done my dynamic `new \DateTime($constraint->max)` stuff inside the custom *DateRangeConstraintValidator* and not the cached custom *DateRangeConstraint*. Just have a look into *Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Range* and *Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\RangeValidator* to see this in action.

### Lessons learned

Your custom *Constraint* class will be serialized and cached and thus shouldn't do any dynamic things. Just validate the options and define the messages and stuff. Your dynamic validation things (and especially the initialization of dynamic parameters) must be done within your custom *ConstraintValidator* class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to look at [Custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html), especially [Class Constraint Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator).

I won't copy paste the whole code, just the parts which you will have to change.

---

Extends the `Constraint` class.

<kbd>src/Acme/DemoBundle/Validator/Constraints/CheckEntryEnteredAt.php</kbd>

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class CheckEntryEnteredAt extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Your error message.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
            return 'CheckEntryEnteredAtValidator';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
            return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

Define the validator by extending the `ConstraintValidator` class, `entryEnteredAt` is the field you want to check:

<kbd>src/Acme/DemoBundle/Validator/Constraints/CheckEntryEnteredAtValidator.php</kbd>

```php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CheckEntryEnteredAtValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $today = new \Datetime('today'); // = midnight

        if ($entity->entryEnteredAt < $today) {
            $this->context->addViolationAt('entryEnteredAt',
                $constraint->message, array(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the validator:

<kbd>src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml</kbd>

```yml
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AcmeEntity:
    constraints:
        - Acme\DemoBundle\Validator\Constraints\CheckEntryEnteredAt: ~
```

---

(adapted from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20472214/2257664))

Comment: This could be a solution, but I wanted to write a generic DateRangeConstraint, not one specific validator for every field I use. Just like other validators as Range. Turns out, that Range can also handle dates, so I don't need a vustom validator at all. So thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @spackmat : feel free to add an answer with your solution, it may help other users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->entryEnteredAt = new \DateTime();
}
```

is something like that a solution for your use case? (on new YourEntity() you'll have a today date set for the entryEnteredAt property)

You could also use LifecycleCallbacks, here is an exemple with preUpdate (there is some more, like PrePersist):

on top of your class entity:

```
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
```

and

```
/** 
* Set updatedAt 
* 
* @ORM\PreUpdate 
*/  
public function setUpdatedAt()  
{  
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();  
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set the date to today, but want to ensure the given date is before (or after) today. But I'll have a look at lifecycle-callbacks, maybe I can implement the check there.