# Check duration of video before uploading

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I'm using symfony 2 for one application I have form to upload video. What I need is to check duration of the video because I need constraint that user cannot upload videos that are more than 1 minute long. So if he tries to upload video longer than 1 minute a mesaage should appear that you cannot upload videos longer than 1 minute.Is there any way I can do this feature.

Comment: You can use a [custom validator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20472214/2257664) to check the length of the video. If you don't know how to get the length of the video, update your question to tell it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on [getID3 library](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/). I do not work with library but i know this can do this